# Canvas getImageData() bizarre issue

Tags: html, canvas, pixel

I have faced quite bizarre issue lately, please take a look at the code snippet below

```
<canvas id="cancan" width="320", height="480">One color image</canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
function imageLoaded(ev) {
    element = document.getElementById("cancan");
    c = element.getContext("2d");

    im = ev.target; // the image, assumed to be 200x200

    // read the width and height of the canvas
    width = element.width;
    height = element.height;

    // stamp the image on the left of the canvas:
    c.drawImage(im, 0, 0);

    // get all canvas pixel data
    imageData = c.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);     
    console.log(imageData.data[0] + " " + imageData.data[1] + " " + imageData.data[2]);
    // output is "243 52 47"
    // matlab and c# output is: "237 36 27"
}

im = new Image();
im.onload = imageLoaded;
im.src = "imgtest1.jpg"; // image is 320x480

</script>
```

imgtest1.jpg used in this example is constant - each pixel is (237,36,27). Pixel color returned by getImageData() differs - it is brighter then what is returned from - for example - matlab - any ideas what could be the reason ?

Comment: It looks similar to a problem I had (no Mathlab nor C# involved) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388106/png-rgb-transformation-related-to-alpha-in-getimagedata

Comment: This could be related to color profiles, gamma correction (as mentioned above) or premultipled alpha (though it doesn't sound like you are testing with a transparent bitmap). If you test this in different browsers, do you get different results?

Answer (score 0):

Lightness or Brightness or Intensity can be computed as (R+G+B)/3 (see HSI color code). After your sample code result, it is obvious that your output-image is a little bit bright than the original one because your R-G-B values are higher than the original ones (from [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.in/products/matlab/trial.html?s_iid=all_trial_ML_ff) or C++).

The question must be "Why your code computes higher values?". I don't know, but you could re-scale the values in order to have the same brightness.